# Assembly bootloader keeps printing S with 'mov ah, 09h'

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86-16, bootloader

every time i try to add color to my assembly bootloader, it always prints "S" and i am not sure why!

Code:

```
            BITS 16
    
    start:
        mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set up 4K stack space after this bootloader
        add ax, 288     ; (4096 + 512) / 16 bytes per paragraph
        mov ss, ax
        mov sp, 4096
    
        mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set data segment to where we're loaded
        mov ds, ax
    
    
        ;setting video mode
        mov ah, 00h
      mov al,00h
      int 10h
        ;setting cursor position
        mov ah, 02h  
        mov dh, 10    ;row 
        mov dl, 45     ;column
        int 10h
    
        mov si, text_string ; Put string position into SI
        call print_string   ; Call our string-printing routine
    
        jmp $           ; Jump here - infinite loop!
    
    
        text_string db 'KRIPKE OS', 0
    
    
    print_string:           ; Routine: output string in SI to screen
    mov ah, 09h
    mov bl, 2  ;colour
    mov cx, 1    ;no.of times

.repeat:
    lodsb           ; Get character from string
    cmp al, 0
    je .done    ; If char is zero, end of string
    int 10h         ; Otherwise, print it
    mov ah, 02h
    add dl, 1
    jmp .repeat

.done:
    ret

    
    
        times 510-($-$$) db 0   ; Pad remainder of boot sector with 0s
        dw 0xAA55       ; The standard PC boot signature
```

Please help me try to fix this.
I think it might be something wrong with the bl register.
Do i need to add an [org 0x7c00] to the top?

output:
[K then lots of spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMC09.png)

Comment: Since you set DS to 0x7c0, you need `[org 0]` instead of `[org 0x7c00]`, since that is the offset from DS at which your code starts.  Maybe it's the default, I'm not sure, but either way it would not hurt to write it explicitly.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I suspect INT 0x10 / AH = 0x09 doesn't update the cursor position after writing.  So you are writing each character on top of the previous ones, and all you see is the last one, which is `S`, and since you set CX to 9 it's repeated 9 times.

Comment: Is there a list of orgs i can use to know what ORIGIN i need?

Comment: @NateEldredge That didnt work :(

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a "list of orgs".  Figuring out what ORG directive to use is just a matter of staying consistent with the way you loaded DS.  It's logic, not reference.

Comment: Show your updated code please.  If you just changed the ORG, then no, that shouldn't be expected to fix it; you should see my second comment instead.  If you added code to move the cursor after each write, then let's see what you wrote.

Comment: i havent written code for that yet, any tips?

Comment: Got it: add dl, 1? in line 43?

Comment: No, the `ah=09h` call doesn't do anything to the cursor position.  You'll need to move your `ah=02h` call inside the loop, and then yes, increment `dl` on each iteration.

Comment: Updated loop: `print_string:   ; Routine: output string in SI to screen
 mov ah, 09h
 mov bl, 2  ;colour
 mov cx, 1    ;no.of times

.repeat:
 lodsb   ; Get character from string
 cmp al, 0
 je .done ; If char is zero, end of string
 int 10h    ; Otherwise, print it
 mov ah, 02h
 add dl, 1
 jmp .repeat

.done:
 ret ` Output: K

Comment: Edit your question with the new code, please; comments are not designed for code and it's not readable.  Or, if it resolved your question, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `int 10h / ah=09h` BIOS call does not update the cursor position, so you would need to repeat your `int 10h / ah=02h`, with an incremented position, after printing each character.  Your current code puts `mov ah, 02h` and `add dl, 1` inside the loop, but does not actually do a second `int 10h` call.  You'll have to reset `ah` to `09h` before each character output call, too.

Better yet, update the cursor position in the loop *before* outputting the character.  This also means that you no longer to set the cursor position before calling `print_string` or entering the loop.

I would write:

```
print_string:           ; Routine: output string in SI to screen
    mov dl, 45      ; initial cursor column column
    mov dh, 10      ; row
    mov bl, 2       ; colour
    mov cx, 1       ; no.of times

.repeat:
    mov ah, 02h     ; update cursor position
    int 10h
    inc dl          ; same as `add dl, 1` but smaller 

    lodsb           ; Get character from string
    cmp al, 0
    je .done        ; If char is zero, end of string
    mov ah, 09h     ; Otherwise, print it
    int 10h         


    jmp .repeat

.done:
    ret
```

For further enhancement, have the caller of `print_string` set the values of `dh,dl` so that it can print at any desired location.  Perhaps also `bl` so that the caller can select the color too.

Comment: To me it prints RIPKE OS not KRIPKE OS. :(

Comment: but when i move dl from 45 to 46 it works. What??

Comment: The first letter of the string is printing at the first set cursor position but why?

Comment: @Louiskoder: Thanks, should be fixed now.  The first iteration of the loop set the cursor column back to 45 so that the second character overwrote the first.